# Find $\left\lfloor\prod_{j=3}^{2020}\log_{j-1}j\right\rfloor$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\log_2 3\cdot\log_3 4\cdot\log_4 5\cdots\log_{2019} 2020=x$

Find the largest natural number which is less than $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\log_{a} b = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$$

Comment: so it becomes $$\frac{\log 2020}{\log 2}$$, then what should i do?

Comment: $=\log_2 2020$. What is $2^{10}$? What is $2^{11}$? So what range will $\log_2 2020$ lie in? What is the largest natural number less than $\log_2 2020$?

Comment: the range will be between 10 and 11, so the answer is 10?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Your product is $\prod_{j=3}^{2020}\frac{\ln j}{\ln (j-1)}$, which telescopes to $\frac{\ln(2020)}{\ln 2}$. Its integer part is $10$.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean "its integer part"

Comment: @NatnichaWeerasin It's a synonym for the floor function you wanted.

Comment: so the answer is 10? and how do you calculate log(2020)?

Comment: @NatnicgaWeerasin $2^{10}=1024<2020<2048=2^{11}$.